# Angular-material: limit md-content height

Tags: css, html, flexbox, angular-material

I've been strugling with some integration issues on angular-material.

On the sample of code below, I'm trying to force the **orange** `div` and the **blue** `div` to have the same height by adding `flex="50"`.
However, an `md-content` child element of the **blue** div containing a large text grows in height whereas it should stay the same and scroll within it's bounds.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oxyBMJ

How can I force the `md-content` element not to grow in height no matter the length of it's content ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: this is working so..the blue div children has scroll and not increasin the height or refine more your problem

Comment: But I would like that the orange and blue div keep the same height. Because in this case, if I add more content to the `md-content`, the turqoise div will grow in height when I would like it to stay the same height and scroll, if you see what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `md-content` as your main container.

```
<md-content layout-fill layout="column">
 <div flex="50" style="border: 5px solid orange" layout="row">
 </div>
 <div flex="50" style="border: 5px solid blue" layout="row">
 </div>
</md-content>
```

This is how your basic structure should look like. Now define flex values as desired and you will get appropriate result. See the below link for your code.

http://codepen.io/next1/pen/vGrWaM

Comment: That's great! But assuming I have a more complex nested structure. How can I achieve the same result in children containers ? For example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vGrdrd

Comment: Pretty much, yes, but can I make it work with the blue div on the left you commented in the code ? Is there a pattern of layout to nest infinitely scrollable md-content ? Thanks for your help

Comment: `row layout` with `flex` works properly if you try. Problem occures when you try to use `column layout` with `flex`. So please check the  `Layout Column and Container Heights`  Section in the following link. https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/tips

Answer (score 1):

you have to give the parent of the two div's a max-height and then you giv md-content `height:100%; and overflow:auto;` like this md-content will stay the same height as  "contact" and they will not grow over the parent and not pusch the upper ones

http://codepen.io/danyweis/pen/oxyZLK

Comment: Thanks mate ! Is there a way to make it a bit more modular without having to specify a limit in pixels ?

Comment: you can limit it in % but the important thing is that the parent has an limited height if not it is not working